# perl regex CSV file and column header manipulation

Tags: regex, perl

First off, I asked a similar question to this and got an answer, but I didn't think about my the values, only the columns.  So...

I have a file with several lines containing headings and values.
Because the values will be inserted into a database, I'd like to use the headings to denote the column names.  So example data is below.

```
Sales-Date,2014-11-01
Item,Truck
Quantity,5,5
Sale Price,6,6
Discount,1,0
Cost of Item,3,3
Profit (loss),2,3
```

I've already ran regexs to remove the parentheses, and dashes from the column headings

I need a regex that looks at the line, and if the heading is One word only, return say the first 4 letters, and if its multiple words, returns the first letter of each word. The comma values need to be returned in all cases. Everything returned is uppercase.  So the desired data would look like:

```
SD,2014-11-01
ITEM,Truck
SP,6,6
DISC,1,0
COI,3,3
PL,2,3
```

Below is the regex code that works if I didn't care about the fields other than the headings.  Sorry, its all I've got, as I said my attempts to modify it have failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my @arr = map {
 local $_ = uc;
 s/\s+\z//;
 /\s/ ? join("", /\b(\w)/g) : /(\w{1,4})/;
}
<DATA>;

print $_, "\n" for @arr;

__DATA__
Sales Date,4,5,6
Item,4,5,6
Sale Price,4,5,6
Discount,4,5,6
Cost of Item,4,5,6
Profit loss,4,5,6
```

If **DATA** contains only the Headings, and no commas or other values, then the output is:

```
SD
ITEM
SP
DISC
COI
PL
```

Comment: This `first letter of each word` can be variable, whats the maximum you expect ?

Comment: Typically when you use a database, you define the column names and create your tables outside of your application. Then your application shoves data into those pre-defined columns. It seems like you're trying to create a database schema on-the-fly. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: @sln, probably up to six or seven words.

Comment: @ThisSuitisBlackNot, Mulitple reasons.  I don't want to create the DB table with Column Headings titled something like Gross Profit (Loss).  I'd rather call it GPL.  And I have hundreds of files to check, and they don't all have the same amount of columns.  I can easily find all the unique columns.  If I format them as per my request above, I can use them to create the DB columns, and I can also then apply that to files so that they will match the DB columns, and makes them great for hash of hash or hash of hash of arrays, and I can easily extract columns and values for DB insertion.

Comment: TL;DR but I see no Perl code

Comment: @tman I would recommend against that approach for several reasons. First, `PL`, `SP`, and `COI` are not great names for database columns; somebody using your database would be hard pressed to know what is stored in those columns without intimate knowledge of your data. Second, your application will have to guess what data type to assign to each column; if your data contains a field like `2001-09-17`, that could be a date, or it could be a serial number. Dates are easier to manipulate when you use the corresponding type provided by your RDBMS (e.g. `DATETIME` in MySQL), *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* but you wouldn't want to store a serial number that way.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your comments, but this DB contains all decimal fields accept the date and company field (and company ID) and it won't be widely used/I'm not concerned with anyone else using it, its for a personal project.

Comment: I would read the file with Perl's built-in Text::CSV module, manipulate each row's columns as appropriate, and then reassemble the output row with Text::CSV.  Doing all this regex stuff on structured data is asking for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a regex that looks at the line, and if the heading is One word only, return say the first 4 letters, and if its multiple words, returns the first letter of each word. The comma values need to be returned in all cases. Everything returned is uppercase.

It's regexes like that, /x mode or not, that makes people call Perl a write-only language.

Why not do this with judicious use split(), substr(), and join()? My boring, readable solution, is below, but the intention of my code is so clear from the implementation of my code that it hardly needs comments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  my ($identifier, @rest) = split(/,/, $line);   
  my @identifier_words = split(/ /, $identifier);
  my $new_identifier = '';
  if (@identifier_words == 1) {
    $abbreviated_identifier = substr($identifier_words[0], 0, 4);
  }
  else {
    foreach my $id_word (@identifier_words) {
      $abbreviated_identfier .= substr($id_word, 0, 1);
    }
  }
  $new_identifier = uc($new_identifier);
  my $new_line = join(',', $abbreviated_identifier, @rest);
  print $new_line;
}

__DATA__
Sales Date,4,5,6
Item,4,5,6
Sale Price,4,5,6
Discount,4,5,6
Cost of Item,4,5,6
Profit loss,4,5,6
```

Comment: If your data is likely to contain fields that have commas in them, then using Text::CSV for the main loop -- and my first split, is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Len, you are right, I should have thought of that, I guess that shows how little I use the substr function.

Comment: The power of Perl's regular expressions, like the dark side of the force, is seductive.

Answer (score 1):

As always, I'd recommend using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) for the actual parsing of CSV files instead of rolling your own solution.

Either way though, the following additional logic can help you with the reformatting of the first field based off the rules you've described:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s{^([^,]*)}{
        my @words = $1 =~ /(\w+)/g;
        uc join '', map { substr $_, 0, @words > 1 ? 1 : 4 } @words;
    }e;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Sales-Date,2014-11-01
Item,Truck
Quantity,5,5
Sale Price,6,6
Discount,1,0
Cost of Item,3,3
Profit (loss),2,3
```

Outputs:

```
SD,2014-11-01
ITEM,Truck
QUAN,5,5
SP,6,6
DISC,1,0
COI,3,3
PL,2,3
```